# How to take a substring from a string and attach another string to the string and convert it to an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have some strings in an array which is in the form of `Exit Survey [hr.exitinterview], Certificate [hr.certificate], Recommendation Letter [hr.recommendation]` I need to extract only `hr.exitinterview, hr.certificate, hr.recommendation` from the existing string and add another string `https://somelink/hr.exitinterview, https://somelink/hr.certificate, https://somelink/hr.recommendation` to every substring and return them to another function as an array. I have tried tried using substring and added the new string to the array, but its just showing `,,,,,`. May I know why or is there anything wrong with the code, I am still learning JS, please ignore if its a stupid question.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var currentTime = new Date();
Logger.log('currentTime:'+ currentTime);
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = data[i][7];
    var links = extract(checkbox);
    Logger.log('New links: ' + links);
  }
}

function extract(data) {
  var lengthOfData = [ data.length];
  if (lengthOfData > 0) {
      var extractedLinks = extractLinks(data);
  }
  if (extractedLinks.length > 0) {
    return extractedLinks;
  }
  else
  {
    return -1;
  }
  return -1;
}

function extractLinks(link) {
  var extractedLinks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i] = JSON.stringify(link[i]);
    extractedLinks.push(link[i].substring(link[i].lastIndexOf("["),link[i].lastIndexOf("]")));
    extractedLinks.map(function(a) { return "https://somelink/" + a; }).join("");
  }
  return (extractedLinks);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the values between the square brackets, and then `map` and `join` them:

```js
const inputs = [
'Exit Survey [hr.exitinterview], Certificate [hr.certificate], Recommendation Letter [hr.recommendation]',
'Exit Survey [aaa], Certificate [bbb], Recommendation Letter [ccc]',
'Exit Survey [qqqqq], Certificate [qwert], Recommendation Letter [12345]',
];
const outputs = inputs.map((input) => {
  const strings = input.match(/[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g);
  const newFullStr = strings
    .map(str => 'https://somelink/' + str)
    .join(', ');
  return newFullStr;
});
console.log(outputs);
```

Array methods are far superior to `for` loops in most cases.

Comment: Oh, OK, Transpile to ES5 with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or just replace the syntax manually.